# Erro: Palavra chave FROM não foi encontrada onde se esperava

Tags: sql, query, oracle

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte inner join mas estou recebendo o erro:

> Palavra chave FROM não foi encontrada onde se esperava

```
select 
       e.num_exame as [exame], 
       a.num_amostra as [amostra], 
       e.data_hora_exame as [exame], 
       a.tipo_amostra as [amostra] 
from exame as e 
inner join amostra as a on e.num_exame = a.num_exame
group by e.num_exame, a.num_amostra, e.data_hora_exame, a.tipo_amostra
where upper (situacao_amostra) like upper ('%descartada%');
```

O que está errado?

Comment: Isso é o que? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres?

Comment: Não vejo nenhum erro a não ser alguma particularidade do dialeto SQL utilizado em seu SGBD, que você não informou qual é. Uma curiosidade: qual o motivo desta cláusula `GROUP BY` se você não utiliza nenhuma função de agregação?

Comment: É Oracle. Tentei comentar o group by mas dá o mesmo erro...

Comment: Tem certeza destes colchetes, o alias não seria entre aspas (ex.: "exame")?

Comment: tentei trocar por aspas e deu o erro: comando SQL não foi terminado corretamente

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.num_exame       as exame, 
       a.num_amostra     as amostra, 
       e.data_hora_exame as dh_exame, 
       a.tipo_amostra    as tipo_amostra
  from exame e inner join amostra a on e.num_exame = a.num_exame
 where upper (situacao_amostra) like upper ('%descartada%')
 group by e.num_exame, a.num_amostra, e.data_hora_exame, a.tipo_amostra
```

Comment: Cláusula where ficou antes do group by, retirada de colchetes, e "as" antes das tabelas